# error in sending e-mail on motion detecting

Tags: raspbian, python, sendemail

I am building motion sensor camera,,, so whenever any motion will be detected it should send email..
i have tried following code for that..

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera
import datetime
import smtplib

def get_file_name():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.h264")
def email():
    content='PIR motion detected'
    mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('myemail','mypassword')
    mail.sendmail('myemail','myemail',content)
    mail.close()   
    return  

sensor=7
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

previous_state=False
current_state=False

cam=picamera.PiCamera()

while True:
 time.sleep(0.01)
 previous_state=current_state
 current_state=GPIO.input(sensor)
 if current_state!=previous_state:
 print "Values outside the function: ", email()
    new_state="HIGH" if current_state else "LOW"
    print("GPIO pin %s is %s"%(sensor,new_state))
    if current_state:
                    fileName=get_file_name()
                    cam.start_preview()
                    cam.start_recording(fileName)

            else:
                    cam.stop_preview()
                    cam.stop_recording()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

but i am getting following error..
 File "t5.py", line 33
    print "Values outside the function: ", email()
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Hello and welcome. While it is not an issue wrt the question, something to consider for future coding: per [PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) *Use 4 spaces per indentation level.*

Comment: You could benefit from using GPIO interrupts rather than polling. `RPI.GPIO` has this feature and is easy to use. That way, you wouldn't have to run the script every 0.01 seconds (!) but could instead do nothing in your `while True` loop except sleeping for hours, have all the action in a callback function and only wake up the script when motion is detected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent this line

```
print "Values outside the function: ", email()
```

because it is part of the if statement above it. Change it to this:

```
 if current_state!=previous_state:
     print "Values outside the function: ", email()
```

This line

```
new_state="HIGH" if current_state else "LOW"
```

looks wrong as well. Is this supposed to be two separate lines? It also has a non python if statement else and no **:**. shouldn't it be something like

```
new_state="HIGH" 
if not current_state:
    current_state = "LOW"
```

As @Ghanima mentioned above your indents should all be 4 spaces. You are using a variety of different indents.

Comment: so can you suggest me a proper indent...

Comment: and where should i have to write calling statement as i am defining function??

Comment: I updated my answer to show you the indent. To call a function you call it from your script outside of the function below its definition. Note comments should not be used to ask a continuing string of questions. Rather you should be asking a new question. However, questions on the basics of Python are off topic here and should be asked on our sister site stackoverflow.com.